# Regarding pivot in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Below you can see my base table. Here I want to pivot rows into columns.

| MATNR | MATERIAL_TEXT | PLANT | WEEK | RUNNING_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | ABC | 1234 | 06 | 116 |
| 1234567890 | ABC | 1234 | 07 | 44 |
| 1234567890 | ABC | 1234 | 08 | 3 |
| 1234567890 | ABC | 1234 | 09 | 43 |
| 1234567890 | ABC | 1234 | 10 | 9 |
| 1234567890 | ABC | 1234 | 11 | 47 |

I have used this query to do so

```
SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT  matnr, material_text, plant, week, running_total
FROM bottom_up_v1    )
PIVOT (sum(running_total) FOR week 
in (06 "KW06", 07 "KW07", 08 "KW08", 09 "KW09", 10 "KW010", 11 "KW011"))
WHERE matnr = '1234567890';
```

But the result shows null for upto calender week 9.

| MATNR | MATERIAL_TEXT | PLANT | KW06 | KW07 | KW08 | KW09 | KW010 | KW011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | Housing | 4320 | Null | Null | Null | Null | 9 | 47 |

This is happening for every material numbers I have tried so far.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: matnr seems different in sample data and query. Also, try to trim week number or to_number as there is possibility some junk character is there with number 06,07.

Comment: Because `'06'` (string) is not `6` (number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have added ' ' in order to consider varchar2 instead of number:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT matnr,
               material_text,
               plant,
               week,
               running_total
          FROM bottom_up_v1)
                          PIVOT (SUM (running_total)
                              FOR week
                              IN ('06' "KW06",
                                 '07' "KW07",
                                 '08' "KW08",
                                 '09' "KW09",
                                 '10' "KW010",
                                 '11' "KW011"))
 WHERE matnr = '8098001500';
```

[image]